# Where can I find config file for Ubuntu 18.04 LXC container?

Tags: networking, lxc

I am trying to test LXC container and created Ubuntu 18.04 container. To access these container from Host Network machines I created new bridged interface in host /etc/network/interfaces and wanted to modify /var/lib/lxc/container-name/config to provide lxc.network.link, lxc.network.ipv4/6, lxc.network.ipv4/6, lxc.network.veth.pair etc. but to my surprise I'm not able to find the config file at this location.
though, I can see default.config file at /etc/lxc.

Following this video for the exercise https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a0dzCzpdUfw

Thanks for any help in Advance!